# No Such Field Error : SASL PROPERTIES on invoking EJB Client

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb-3.0

I am trying to invoke EJB but get SASL PROPERTY: No such filed error. I have added SASL jar "jboss-sasl-1.0.0.Beta1.jar" as a dependency too.

This is my code:

```
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.put("endpoint.name", "client-endpoint");
        properties.put("remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED", "false");
        properties.put("remote.connections", "default");
        properties.put("remote.connection.default.host", "localhost");
        properties.put("remote.connection.default.port", "4447");
        properties.put("remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS", "false");
        properties.put("remote.connection.default.username", "user");
        properties.put("remote.connection.default.password", "pass");

        EJBClientConfiguration cc = new PropertiesBasedEJBClientConfiguration(properties);

        final ContextSelector<EJBClientContext> ejbClientContextSelector = new ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector(cc);

        final ContextSelector<EJBClientContext> previousSelector = EJBClientContext.setSelector(ejbClientContextSelector);              

        StatelessEJBLocator<SomeClass> locator = new StatelessEJBLocator(SomeClass.class, "app", "module", "viewType", "distinctName");               

        SecurityDomainService ejb =  org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClient.createProxy(locator);`
```

But I get this exception:

`java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SASL_PROPERTIES
    org.jboss.ejb.client.PropertiesBasedEJBClientConfiguration.<clinit>(PropertiesBasedEJBClientConfiguration.java:79)`

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was getting this error because I wasn't using the correct EJB Client jar.

I guess `jboss-ejb-client-1.0.16.Final.jar` introduced this field, and it works fine when used with this jar.